# Only select from files on SD card in BookEen Odyssey

Tags: ebook-readers, cybook

When I insert a SD card in my Bookeen Odyssey which contain my study Books, the titles show up mixed with my 'pleasure' books on the internal memory of the bookreader.

I can add "AA" before the book title or author name and make sure they are sorted together, but maybe there is a better way of organising that I missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Folder View, you can select the folder view, which probably gives you `Cybook/.../` etc. at the top. Then select the parent directory in the top-left corner of the display repeatedly until you see a `Cybook` and an `SD` icon. The top will read `Library`.

Select `SD` and after that navigate to the books in the (sub)folder on your SD card.

(If you happen to switch on folder view while reading a book from your SD card, you will already 'be' in a directory on your SD card, and you will  not have `Cybook` at the beginning of your directory path).

Also see the question [Where can I see the books that are stored in my SD card?](http://www.bookeen.com/support?idPart=3&idCategory=8)